# Archiving SharePoint Sites Removing Permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, archive

A team separate from mine has started Archiving SharePoint sites and selecting the options to not delete the sites.

Permissions for the archived sites are being removed when this happens. It seems obvious to me that this should happen as the whole point of archiving a site is if it is no longer being used. However I have not been able to locate any proof that archiving sites would remove permissions.

Is there any official documentation that states archiving sites removes permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a feature in SharePoint, but more of a governance and policy question around the application. Archiving can take on a different meaning to whomever you ask.

To me, archiving is making permissions read-only on all content. It is accessible if needed, but it is no longer being actively being worked on.

If their policy is to remove permissions, then to me, it isn't so much archiving but seeing if people notice the content is gone prior to deleting it all.

Comment: From my understanding they are using an archiving tool. This is not a built in tool on any of the 2010 versions?

Comment: No, there isn't a built in archive system in SharePoint. Perhaps it is a tool they wrote or purchased.